# What can I use to simulate dependency of variables?

Tags: windows, open-source, math, programming, simulation

I'd like to write the relationship between 2, 3 or even more variables and plotting out that in 2 and possibly 3 dimensional graphs, with the ability to calculate the possible range of the other values at a given value for one variable.

I remember to see similar things in XFuzzy, but I want something more user-friendly.

Very rough example:
[image]

(edit: interactive 3D or at least 2D plots as result would be great)

Comment: What should be the output of the solution? A static image? An interactive image? A mathematical model?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul do you think this terrible sketch belongs to the main post? It looks awkward IMHO.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul anyways to answer your question, I thought of interactive plots.

Comment: Yes, everything must be in the body of the answer. About "interactive plots", please add that to the body too, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [**Weka**](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)?

It's a versatile machine learning software containing different tools for interpolation, ... I think it would be useful for you.

> Weka is a collection of machine learning algorithms for data mining tasks. The algorithms can either be applied directly to a dataset or called from your own Java code. Weka contains tools for data pre-processing, classification, regression, clustering, association rules, and visualization. It is also well-suited for developing new machine learning schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Octave (If linux) and matlab can easily plot data in that form. Plots have properties in them. Matplotlib in python can